# 4次元データをPythonで図示したい

Tags: python

スペクトログラムのデータを重ねて3次元のグラフを作成したいのですが、どのようにコードを書けばいいのか全く分かりません。

**スペクトログラムのデータ (例) :**

[image]

スペクトラムのデータは、2次元配列で保存されており、この2次元配列が400個あります。

上記の事柄が実現可能なライブラリーであればなんでもいいです。

スペクトグラムが3次元です。そのデータが400層（個）あります。なので、これらで3次元のグラフを表示したいです。

Comment: この辺が参考になるかも。[pythonで3Dプロット](https://python-climbing.com/python-3dplot/), [Python spectrogram in 3D (like matlab's spectrogram function)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56788798/9014308), [How to obtain spectrogram of a 3D accelerometer file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47518937/9014308)

Comment: タイトルには 4 次元と書かれていますが、4 次元配列に格納されたデータを 3 次元空間に描画したいということであっていますか？

Comment: 例えば[この様なプロット図](https://blog.endaq.com/hubfs/Blog-Images/aircraft-vibration-spectrogram-example.svg)を描画したい、という事でしょうか？

Comment: 実際のデータは無くても良いので、データの形が分かるように読み込み部分のプログラムだけでもあると話が伝わりやすくなるのかな、と思いました。